# Toolbar title not visible with CollapsingToolBarLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-toolbar, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <!--    ******************    TOOLBAR    *******************    -->
    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|snap"

        >
        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|snap"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            >
        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
```

Hello everyone.
My toolbar is not visible even though I have set it in my activity with:

```
(toolbar.setTitle("TITLE");
        toolbar.setTitleTextColor(0xFFFFFF);
```

I have provided a snip of my .XML file. 
Since I am a noob, I'm requesting the stackoverflow army for help.

Thanks a lot for helping me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to set in in your Activity  you can use support action bar like this.

on **`onCreate`**

```
     setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

then later when you are going to set your title try this.

```
     if (getSupportActionBar() != null) {
        if (title!=null) {
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle(title);
        } else {
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        }
    }
```

If not you may use xml option too:

```
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    app:title="TITLE"
    app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">
```

Hope it helps.